# Performing an action on cookie expiration

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

What I want to do it cause an action when a cookie expires. For example i have a cookie:

```
setcookie('loggedIn', true, time()+ 3600);
```

When the cookie expires I would like to be able to redirect them to a different web page automatically and call a php script that would log the user out.

Comment: [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are more suitable for login management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it via `$_COOKIE`.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['loggedIn'])){
  header('Location: /path/to/another/page');
  exit;
}
```

You can code it in a separate file and include it in every page OR you can implement it in XHR.

Comment: I though about that but it would mean including it on every page. I was looking for a more general solution where on cookie expiration a script would automatically be run rather then only on page load (which is when that would need to be run).

Comment: @yitzih You can write it in a separate file and include it in every page? OR you can implement it in XHR

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though what you're trying to do is automatically log users out after some amount of time. **Cookie expiration is not an appropriate way to do this** — the expiration date of a cookie can be changed by the user, and cookies can be deleted without reaching their expiration date. (For instance, if a user clears cookies in their browser, or uses a private browsing session.)

An appropriate way to log a user out automatically would be to store the expiration date in the session, e.g.

```
// during login
$_SESSION["valid_until"] = time() + 3600 * 3; // stay logged in for three hours

// then, during page startup
if ($_SESSION["valid_until"] < time()) {
    session_destroy(); // or store data in the session to indicate it's inactive
    header("Location: error.php?err=session-timeout");
    exit();
}
```